# How would use span to create different styles between selected characters and the rest?

Tags: css, xhtml

Let's say I have `<p>hi my name is john</p>`. I'm aware that I can use `span` to select the characters, and then use CSS to make their styles different from the rest of the text. However, if I want "name" and "john" to be different from the rest of the sentence, and from each other, is this even possible? If so, how is this achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I miss the point, but it sounds like you've answered your own question. You seem to know that you can wrap `hi` and `john` in span tags and then apply css to style them.

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Vqk/

```
p span:first-child {  }
p span:last-child {  }

<p><span>hi</span>my name is <span>John</span></p>
```

Or alternatively use class names

http://jsfiddle.net/ZegR2/

```
span.foo {  }
span.bar {  }

<p><span class="foo">hi</span>my name is <span class="bar">John</span></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yo can use `~` selector for this. write like this:

```
p span{ color: red;  }
p span ~ span{color:green}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/W4Vqk/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this

```
<p>hi my <span>name</span> is <span>john</span></p>
```

in css

```
p span { color:#666666; }
```

if want different styles for name and john just give different class for both span tags